# External REST Service Authentication from SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, authentication, sharepoint, office365, adal

Often creating complex business application using SharePoint Online, I need to externalize business logic to external service in order to use .net code and third-party assemblies.

In my case I'm developing a Rest Service hosted by an Azure Web Site.

[Here my architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1W7q.png)

My question is:

Can I obtain an access Token from SharePoint, containing the current user information, pass it to external Rest Service and then reuse it to return and autenticate the user to SharePoint using the current user credentials?

This service is called from both JavaScript code both 2013 workflows

Can you give me documentation about it?

Thanks,

Sergio

Answer (score 0):

> > External REST Service Authentication from SharePoint Online…This service is called from both JavaScript code both 2013 workflows

The SharePoint online is protected by Azure AD by default.  Based on the description, there are two kinds of authentication scenario. First is that you want call the custom REST service without authentication after you login the SharePoint online. 
The second is that you can call the REST service by get the token exchange with the credential of SharePoint online users.

In the first scenario, we can integrate Open Connect ID to authenticate the REST service. And in the second scenario, we can use OAuth 2.0 to integrate the Azure AD.

Here are the main steps to demo the solution:

1. Register an web app on Azure AD
2. Create an MVC and Web API project
3. Add the code below to use Open connect ID and OAuth 2.0 in
   ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) method(Startup.Auth.cs)

   ```
   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
       new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
       {
           ClientId = "5efa8abc-13dc-4681-83f5-c6fde07116ac",
           Authority = "https://login.windows.net/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
           PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:24865/",
       });

       app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
       {
               Audience = "https://yourtenant-my.sharepoint.com/",
               Tenant = "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
       });
   ```

You can refer to links below about more detail about protected resource by Azure AD:

[Web App Sign In & Sign Out with Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/)

[Protect a Web API using Bearer tokens from Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet/)

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your response.

My request is not logging me in my WebApi service, Anonymous authentication is right for me.

I would like to authenticate my service (CSOM or rest) into SharePoint site using the credential of the user who called my service.

Is it possibile?
How can I get the STSToken from SharePoint to be reused inside my web api service?

Thanks a lot,
Sergio

Comment: You can reuse the token from SharePoint via add the code "app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication". You can go to [here](https://jwt.io/) to retrieve the audience in the token, and replace it and you tenant in the code sample above. And I also upload the [MVCProtecedByAzureAD](https://github.com/VitorX/OfficeDEVSamples/tree/master/MVCProtecedByAzureAD) project for test.